# Github Repository Details with Repo ID

Tags: c#, github, github-api, octokit, octokit.net

I am using Octokit Nuget Package for Github. I need to get the result as per the figure attached [image: Github Details]

I am using the following method for getting details of the Repository

```
public JsonResult GetRepositoryDeatil(long id)
    {
        var client = new GitHubClient(new ProductHeaderValue("demo"));
        var tokenAuth = new Credentials("xxxxxxx"); // NOTE: not real token
        client.Credentials = tokenAuth;
        var content = client.Repository.Content.GetAllContents(id).Result;
        List<RepositoryContent> objRepositoryContentList = content.ToList();

        return Json(objRepositoryContentList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Output JSON can be viewed at the following link [Output JSON](https://api.myjson.com/bins/1f6ilz)

I am not able to get the commit details but only the directory or the file detail. Please suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: Please update your post to show the actual JSON being output.

Comment: @mjwills Added can you please have a look and help if you know about the Octokit package.

Answer (score 0):

To get the current commit for a given branch, and the files that have changed:

```
var currentCommit = await client.Repository.Commit.Get(id, "master");
var commitMessage = currentCommit.Commit.Message;
var files = currentCommit.Files;
```

The timestamp is buried in the author and committer fields, but aren't surfaced in the C# library currently.